# XML Xpath expression

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to get the elements **title** and **runtime** (siblings) where the runtime value is larger than the input value. My C# code with the XPath expression is:

```
ElementValue = 140;

nodeList = root.SelectNodes(@"/moviedb/movie[./runtime>'" + ElementValue + "'/title | /moviedb/movie[./runtime>'" + ElementValue + "']/runtime");
```

This XPath expression is not returning anything.

My XML file:

```
  <moviedb>
      <movie>
        <imdbid>tt0120689</imdbid>
        <genres>Crime,Drama,Fantasy,Mystery</genres>
        <languages>English,French</languages>
        <country>USA</country>
        <rating>8.5</rating>
        <runtime>189</runtime>
        <title lang="english">The Green Mile</title>
        <year>1999</year>
      </movie>
      <movie>
        <imdbid>tt0415800</imdbid>
        <genres>Action,Animation,Drama,Thriller</genres>
        <languages>English</languages>
        <country>USA</country>
        <rating>4.5</rating>
        <runtime>139</runtime>
        <title lang="english">Fight Club</title>
        <year>2004</year>
      </movie>
    </moviedb>
```

Comment: What is `nodeList` and what is `root`. We can guess, but create a complete sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can instead use linq2xml

```
var doc=XDocument.Load(path);
var movies=doc.Elements("movie")
              .Where(x=>(int)x.Element("runtime")>input)
              .Select(x=>new 
                     {
                         Title=x.Element("title").Value,
                         Runtime=(int)x.Element("runtime")
                     });
```

You can now iterate over movies

```
foreach(var movie in movies)
{
    movie.Title;
    movie.Runtime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be applying the values you want off the node as a filter criteria, which won't work. I would go about this another way, first finding the nodes which meet the criteria:

```
nodeList = root.SelectNodes(@"/moviedb/movie[runtime > " + ElementValue + "]");
```

And then grabbing the child elements from each:

```
foreach (var node in nodeList)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText);
    Debug.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("runtime").InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a single XPath expression by performing a `union` i.e. the `|` operator. As mentioned in other answers here, you had your select inside your predicate which would not result in the correct answer for you anyway.

Note, if you want to see if a number is bigger than another number, unless you are using a Schema driven data-type aware XQuery engine you will need to cast the `text()` to a number before performing the comparison. In this instance I have assumed an `xs:int` will be suitable for you. Also you can use the atomic `gt` as opposed to `=`  which *may* be more efficient.

```
ElementValue = 140;

nodeList = root.SelectNodes(@"/moviedb/movie[xs:int(runtime) gt " + ElementValue + "]/(title | runtime)");
```